# Creating a meal planner in React (MERN), wanting to reuse a component for adding and editing meals

Tags: reactjs, frontend, mern

I’m creating a meal planner and I want to use the same modal component to add and edit meals, because they are exactly the same. The modal includes inputs for name, ingredients and the day of the week to make it. When adding new meals, I want the modal inputs to be empty and when editing I want the inputs to have the current data so the user doesn’t have to re-enter all of it.

My attempt so far has been to enter a prop string to the PlannerModal that is either “add” or “edit” and either do a fetch post or put depending on that prop. This seems to work ok, but I’m running into the problem of setting the data into the inputs with the value attribute which I do not want when adding a meal, so I’m thinking there has to be a better way of organizing all of this, aside from creating two different modals.

[image]

[image]

My component hierarchy looks like this if it helps:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem with your approach, However, there are a few improvements I can come up with, first, instead of passing “add” or “edit” as string, you should try using enum in this scenario, and I assume the issue you are having is caused by having the `value` property, if that's the case, you can do something like

```
const inputProps = 
props.mode === Mode.Edit 
? {onChange: ...., value: something} 
: {value: something, disabled: true}
```

and then you should be able to spread the `inputProps` into your input element like

```
<input {...inputProps} />
```

sounds a bit confusing but just giving you an idea to pas props optionally